# Generate exponentially increasing list of numbers (from start to stop)

Tags: python, list

I would like to generate a exponentially increasing list of numbers between a start and an end number.

So for example I would to take:
`start_num = 700,000`
`end num = 750,000`
`num_steps = 100`

and generate a list of 100 numbers roughly like so:`[700000,700100,700250,700700.....746000,750000]`

I can do this for evenly spaced intervals with `np.arange` or even slightly exponentially increasing with `np.logspace` but the "sharpness" of the increase is not enough with this method.

Ideally I could also control how sharp the increase in distance would be.\\

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what would be the factor of increasing exponent ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have an exponential increase change when working between a fixed `start` and `end`. The problem is that you want different equations `y = Ab^x` but `A` and `b` are two variables dependent on `start` and `end` only. i.e. for any `start, end` you can always solve for the unique equation `y = f(x) = Ab^x` s.t. `f(0) = start` and `f(num_steps) = end`

Comment: The "sharpness" in `np.logspace` increases with the base.

Comment: @Goyo no it doesn't, look at my answer

Comment: @FHTMitchell Right, I was thinking of makig the distances betwen numbers to lie on an exponential instead of the numbers themselves. That is certainly not the same thing but the OP seems to refer to the latter at first and to the former at the end.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comments, your premise is mathematically flawed. Essentially you want, given fixed `start`, `stop` and `num` (num_steps) an equation (this is maths, **not** python)

```
y = f(x) = Ab^x
```

with "boundary conditions"

```
f(0) = start
f(num) = stop
```

Now this is relatively easy to solve for the only two constants -- the coefficient `A` and the base `b`:

```
f(0) = Ab^0 = A => A = start

f(num) = start * b^(num) => b = (stop / start) ^ (1 / num)
```

So if we chose a `start`, `stop` and `num` we cal solve for **all** constants in our equation `y`. There is nothing to vary, so you must always get the same result.

This can be seen by doing:

```
import numpy as np
import math

for b in range(2, 6):
    # np.logspace takes start and stop as the exponent of base
    # so use math.log for consistency -- same as np.geomspace
    print(np.logspace(math.log(2, b), math.log(10, b), num=5, base=b))
```

Outputs

```
[ 2.          2.99069756  4.47213595  6.68740305 10.        ]
[ 2.          2.99069756  4.47213595  6.68740305 10.        ]
[ 2.          2.99069756  4.47213595  6.68740305 10.        ]
[ 2.          2.99069756  4.47213595  6.68740305 10.        ]
```

---

#### Edit:

n.b. the equation given is the general exponential equation -- any equation of the form `y = ab^(kx + c)` can be rewritten as `y = (ab^c)(b^k)^x = AB^x`.

Note that this does not include the non-exponential equation `y = C + Ab^x` (see comments). If you want to use this version with a variable base, then this function will do the trick

```
def varlogspace(start, stop, num, base, **kwargs):
    n = num - 1
    c = (start - stop) / (1 - base**n)
    a = start - c
    def f(x):
        return a + (c * base**x)
    return np.fromfunction(f, (num,), **kwargs)


for b in range(2, 6):
    print(varlogspace(2, 5, 5, base=b))
```

outputs (see that increasing `base` increases the curvature of the curve)

```
[2.  2.2 2.6 3.4 5. ]
[2.    2.075 2.3   2.975 5.   ]
[2.         2.03529412 2.17647059 2.74117647 5.        ]
[2.         2.01923077 2.11538462 2.59615385 5.        ]
```

Comment: Hhm.. why not start with `f(x) = a + b^x`? seems a bit more logical choice for this kind of problem to me since you can solve `a` by looking sharply at the problem: `f(0) = 699,999 + b^0`. And all that's left to do is determine `b` with the help of our boundary condition `b^99 = 50K+1` or am i missing something here?

Comment: Because `f(x) = a + b^x` is not an [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) since it doesn't satisfy the equation `df/dx = Cf(x)`. If OP was happy to use an exponential spacing with a constant shift `a` then you could do what OP wants since you'd then have three constants in the equation `g(x) = a + Cb^x` which would allow you to vary one (presumably `b`).

Comment: Oh, well good point ... depending on where this task was presented a strict definition might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
num=0
numlist=[]
for i in range(700000,750000):
    if num==100:
        break

    if i+num*100>750000:
        num=num/2
    numlist.append(i+num*100)
    num+=1
print(numlist)
```

This code dependse of number place and it can increasly generate numbers

Comment: Eh, sure this generates numbers but they are evenly spaced, so linear with x. Btw: same numlist can be created by simply defining a function `def f(x): return 700000 + x*101` and calling it like: `for i in range(100): numlist.append(f(i))`

Comment: Can we use random numbers in your program? for example cam we append random number to your generated numbers?

Comment: Sure you can: you just need to import a random function like randint: `from random import randint` and use it: `my_list.append(randint(0,100))` to add a number between zero and 100.

Answer (score -1):

```
start = 0
stop = 100
factor = 2
step = 0
numlist = []

while start < stop:
    numlist.append(start)
    step += factor
    start += step    

print(numlist)

# Output
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]
```

I made this simple code that would increase the step as per the factor you chose like in this case it is step increases by 2 as it goes to the end. Unfortunately you have to sacrifice landing exactly on stop if you want if you want to control the factor. Hope it helps in solving your problem.